# how to solve the problem no connection could be made because the target machine actively refused C# HttpClient

Tags: c#, asp.net

I try to run this code in asp.net core

```
 HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
 client.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30);
 client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://192.168.10.25/");
HttpResponseMessage getTokenresponse = client.GetAsync("api/getToken/getitss?username=Ahmad&password=ahmad@123").Result;
 var a = getTokenresponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
 string token = a.Result.Replace(@"""", "").Replace(@"\", "");
```

when I run the code and debug it the code makes me an error like this:
no connection could be made because the target machine actively refused, in postman, it work for me and give me the token but when I run it in c# code it give me an error.
can anyone help me
thanks

Comment: you are missing port no in the url.

Comment: Is port 80 open for HTTP connections? If not then which port? If it's actually HTTPS then it's all wrong, as you haven't specified HTTPS and you can't usually connect using the IP address. Side note: do not use `.Result` as it can deadlock, use `await` instead

Comment: @Charlieface thanks for answer I used HTTPS now I changed it to HTTP but still gives me the same error like this: HttpRequestException: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it. (127.0.0.1:13847), The same code works for me in another asp.net core application but the current project gives me this error, can you tell me how to enable port 80 for HTTP connection in the current project?

Comment: Where does port 13847 come from, it's not in your code? Which port is the application listening on? Check the Bindings in IIS